# JVM crash related msvcrt.dll

Tags: java, windows

while use code as below, it looks like windows issue, somebody can help?
your can refere me for `mdmp` file

i changed different JDKs, but seems same issue

```
#        OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystem = #ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
#        if (operatingSystem instanceof com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) {
#            com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ###(com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) operatingSystem;
#            osBean.getSystemCpuLoad()
#        }


C  [msvcrt.dll+0x74452]
C  [MozartBreathCore.dll+0x1ffb0]
C  [MozartBreathCore.dll+0xcb1b5]
C  [MozartBreathCore.dll+0x306935]
C  [MozartBreathCore.dll+0x3a732b]
...
C  [management.dll+0x3419]
C  0x0000000003528a07

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl.getSystemCpuLoad()D+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain to us what do you mean by "your can refere me for mdmp file"? This can help us to solve the issue : )

Comment: mdmp file is minidump file  when JVM crashed which can help location the issue